# LOCK TABLES `ABC` WRITE is not working in liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Below is one of my changeset(MYSQL db):

```
- changeSet:
        id: 7
        author: vikas
        changes:
            - sql:
                sql: LOCK TABLES `ABC` WRITE;        
        rollback:
            - sql:
                sql: 
        tagDatabase:
            tag: version_1.6
```

I use this before insert command. But I am getting error :

> Error setting up or running Liquibase: Table 'DATABASECHANGELOG' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
>   [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID, TAG) VALUES ('7', 'vikas', 'src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog/02-db-changelog.yml', NOW(), 7, '8:a1203076d34b717e77bc2d929a4c03dc', 'sql; tagDatabase', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.1', '1300532106', 'version_1.6')]

Comment: It looks like you locked the table `DATABASECHANGELOG` which is a central table in liquibase to keep track of your changesets. Just a guess: You wrote "`LOCK TABLES ...`" which might lock all tables. But maybe you just need to write "`LOCK TABLE 'ABC'...`". So unlock all tables, correct your changeset and try again...

Comment: I have written `LOCK TABLES ABC WRITE` only. Please see my above changeset sql

Comment: I know. But you should write `LOCK TABLE ABC WRITE`. `TABLE` not `TABLES`.

Comment: Tried running the with LOCK TABLE ABC WRITE. Still getting the same error. Do I have to use aliase as suggested here? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Did you unlock the tables first?

Comment: Yes. Even tried with deleting the whole database and creating new but still getting the error